# Making journal titles in IEEE Access Overleaf latex template appear in italics and references to display DOI information

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, doi, ieeeaccess

**I need help in making the titles of journals in my IEEE Access overleaf latex template appear in italics. Below is the screenshot of my document preamble**

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess} 

\usepackage{cite} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}

\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}
```

**This is how my references were called**

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
```

**This is a screenshot of how my references appeared**
[image]

**I want the journal name components (i.e. IEEE Access, IEEE Transactions on Industrial Informatics, The 25th Annual International Conference on Mobile Computing and Networking, etc) to appear in italics and the DOI component of each reference to be displayed.**

**This is a screenshot of my bib file**
[image]

**I really don't know where I made the mistake but my output references are not in the IEEE Access format.**

**This is a screenshot of the default files in my overleaf template apart from my inputted figures**
[image]

**I need assistance in figuring out how to get the correct IEEE Access reference format.**

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue using `biblatex`.

I removed the `\usepackage{cite}` command and introduced

```
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myref.bib}
```

I replaced all the `\cite` commands with `\parencite` and outputted my references with the `\printbibliography` command.

The resulting output is shown in the screenshot below
[image]

Comment: Do keep in mind though, that changing the template significantly may lead to problems when you try to submit your article to the publisher. `biblatex` needs a *very* different workflow than the usual BibTeX-based bibliography used in IEEE templates, so that could be an issue.

Comment: Given that many publishers post-process submissions with non-LaTeX tools anyway, the IEEE may be fine with your submitting your article using their template. It is possible that they will iron out small details that are not quite right themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your input @moewe. Will these likely problems results if the final submission is actually a pdf file and not a tex file?

Comment: Logically, using `biblatex` would indeed be less of an issue when you only ever submit PDFs and the publisher never requests your `.tex` files. But even then there might be subtle differences between `biblatex` and `IEEEtran` that could be an issue, so I would probably not 'risk it'.